# What are the current options for basic web-based video editing?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video-encoding, video-editing

I'm wondering what options exist as of April 2011 for allowing a user to, having uploaded a piece of video to our server:

- Trim the footage by indicating a start and end point
- Capture specific frames to use as a thumbnail / snapshot for the video.

Transcoding is no problem - we have various wrappers around `ffmpeg` that are doing this just fine - but in terms of providing a web interface, I'm not sure where to begin.

HTML5, Flash or Silverlight options - or even Java applets, I guess - would all be worth considering. Open source is always a bonus.

Comment: Last time i looked at this (a couple of years ago), the only way to get frame accurate control was to develop an ActiveX control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company does this, http://www.forbidden.co.uk/ Based in Wimbledon UK. We mainly use a java frontend to cloud-based backend. But there is an Android version too.

Our core business is editing for professional TV productions. But we have various sorts of possible integration, and do things like thumbnailing and frame extraction into facebook etc.

Not open source I'm afraid, but a lot of our infrastructure is, linux based ingester etc.